# how to remove element in specified index without shiftingelements

Tags: iphone, objective-c

im using nsmutabltearray in my code base  and i want to remove an element within a specified index. i know that element will be shifted automatically.

but i want to stop this . elements shouldn't be shifted within the indexes. 
ex - : arraylist in java

is thr any specied list tyoe in objc to do this

Thank you

Comment: You want to delete 1 object from array and other elements should not be shifted. right?

Comment: Maybe use a `NSDictionary` with appropriate keys instead of an array?  That should do what you want, although it will take a little more work to calculate the keys....

Comment: Please tell more about why you need this.  There's probably a good use of collection classes that will make it work.  NSDictionary (as Inafziger points out) sound promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the default NS(Mutable)Array. Instead of removing, you could put `[NSNull null]` objects in there, but methods like `count` and `objectAtIndex` would still return the same values, so that may not be of much help either.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)replaceObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withObjects:(NSArray *)objects
```

method can be used and put in a null object in the place of thte position where you want to remove the content